Can $I^{-1}_x(a,a)$ be expressed via $I_x(a,a)$ and vice versa?
Here $I_x(a,a)$ is the Beta regularized function $I_x(a,b) = \frac{B(x;\,a,b)}{B(a,b)}$ and $I^{-1}_x(a,b)$ is its inverse.
Now consider functions $I^{-1}_x(a,a)$ and $I_x(a,a)$ (second and third arguments coincide). Can they be expressed via each other? They seemingly produce similar families of curves:


The graphs seem to be closest, without intersecting, when the derivatives at $x=\frac12$ are equal. This means $I^{-1}_x(a,a)\approx I_x(b,b)$ where $\frac{4^{1 - a}}{B(a, a)}=B(b, b) 4^{b-1}$.  For natural $a$, one needs to put a polynomial in terms of the inverse of one and likely they cannot be put in terms of one another for other values.
